# Слитно или раздельное написание

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Будьте добры, подскажите, слитно или раздельно: несколько не()отмытых пятен

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***несколько неотмытых пятен.***

При отсутствии зависимых слов НЕ с причастием пишется слитно.

***Несколько***  не является зависимым словом, это неопределенно-количественное числительное, образующее счетный оборот: ***несколько пятен.***

Сравнить: *несколько не отмытых **при стирке** пятен.* Здесь раздельное написание НЕ при наличии зависимого слова.